# if value more than DAX Query

Tags: dax

I am trying to make a simple DAX query where if the value is more than 8 it should be consider as a 8

As an example

```
if value is 24 consider as 8
```

So whenever the value is 8 or more than 8, it should be 8.

How i can do that in a DAX query or in a POWER Query !

I have search a lot here ---

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634907.aspx

but did not find any solution !

Do anyone knows any solution to this problem !

Answer (score 2):

Power Query

```
// Add new custom field
Max8 =
if [FieldName] > 8
then 8
else [FieldName]
```

DAX

```
// Calculated column
Max8 =
IF(
    'TableName'[FieldName] > 8
    ,8
    ,'TableName'[FieldName]
)

// As a measure to test another measure's return value
Max8:=
IF(
    [MeasureName] > 8
    ,8
    ,[MeasureName]
)
```

Comment: I have no idea what your comment means. I'll try to respond anyway. 'then' is a keyword only in Power Query's M language. DAX has no 'then' keyword or function. IF() is a function in DAX whose second argument is evaluated when the first argument evaluates to true and whose third argument is evaluated if the first argument evaluates to false.

Answer (score 1):

Use the two parameter version of the [MIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/query-bi/dax/min-function-dax) function:

```
MIN('TableName'[FieldName], 8)
```

This gives you the smaller of `'TableName'[FieldName]` and `8`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar situation by using AND and Nested IF

```
RANK = IF(AND(STUDENT[SCORE] >= 50, STUDENT[SCORE] <=100),"One" , "Two")
```